# Linear Algebra assumption

Tags: linear-algebra

If the determinant of a set of vectors is not zero, then it's linearly independent.
Since its linearly independent, it can span and form a basis in $\mathbb R^n$.

Am I right to assume this if the determinant is not zero? If not, what do I need to do in order to say it spans and form a basis?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to be clear what you mean by "determinant of a set of vectors," namely, you mean the determinant of the matrix whose columns (or rows, if you prefer) are the given vectors. And of course determinant only makes sense for square matrices, so you have to understand that your set of vectors has exactly $n$ vectors in it. But if you understand all that, then you are fine: if the determinant is not zero, then the set is a basis.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson yea that's what I meant, sorry for not being clear. If the set of vectors doesn't form a square matrix then, as a substitute, would I need to find the rank of the matrix that corresponds with the dimension in order to determine linear independence and then can assume what I stated above?

Comment: If you have fewer than $n$ vectors, they can't span. If you have more than $n$ vectors, they can't be linearly independent. In either case, they can't be a basis.